# Set Extract Imacros br

Tags: imacros

I have tried to output 3 lines of data but not as expected

1. Nancy D. Feather
2. 3929 Henry Ford Avenue
3. Tulsa, OK 74133

   Results run code

   Nancy D. Feather

   3929 Henry Ford AvenueTulsa, OK 74133

[enter link description here](https://sv1.uphinhnhanh.com/images/2018/08/12/ggg.jpg)

I have tried this imacros code

```
VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.fakenamegenerator.com/
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:adr* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR2 {{!EXTRACT}}
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}<br>{{!VAR2}}
```

I started to learn imacros pro, please help me get the desired output!

Comment: @VTDiesgner Your code works fine! tested with version `Imacros for Firefox 9.0.3`

Comment: Thank you very much see my code
The results I need like this

Maria W. Adams
2490 Bubby Drive
Austin, TX 78744

extract false results

Linda H. Rodriguez
4459 Monroe AvenueCape Haze, FL 33946

Comment: Both of them look the same, what is the difference?

Comment: You link the photo above
I can not picture the post

Comment: has anyone come across help with

Comment: Sorry I am unable to find the solution, could you please raise a question in Imacros forums, also please state the reason for using the code!